# TestFlight error "Your request couldn't be completed"?

Tags: ios, download, testflight

I'm testing an iOS App using TestFlight.
I have already successfully tested 8 Build pre-release but now it is not working anymore.
I have upload the built and it has been approved by Apple, invitations to external testers has been sent and properly received, but when they open TestFlight and try to download the App the download stops just before the end and an alertView says:

```
Your request couldn't be completed
```

NOTES:
I have tried the download on different devices but none has worked.
TestFlight is incrementing installation count also if none download has been completed.
I have upload the built today in the morning.

Comment: Same is happening to me. Think it's an itunes connect problem

Comment: I have this happening with one of my test users.  Everybody else is ok.  This user is also able to install other apps from TestFlight without a problem.

Answer (score 13):

Found solution.

Latest XCode version changed the default build code signing identity to Developer, when it should be Distribution to work with TestFlight.
While it throw any error while uploading, it's the one causing the problem.

Just change it and it will work again

Comment: Pretty annoying that the new Xcode automatically inputs these bad default values. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

An external tester of us received the "Your Request couldn’t be completed. Try again." error when he received an invitation before the app was actually approved for external testing, due to an error at Apple's side.

After **re-inviting** the same user, the TestFlight build went to the "Waiting for Review" status, which eventually fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue/bug. It appears you can share the app while it is under review and it can't be installed.

Comment: @wmcnally I filed a Feedback for this, and even received a request from Apple for more info. Apparently it's still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is putting the test user under interal testing then accepting the email invite saying to open testflight and I had no problems

ALSO make sure you do not have the app installed already through xcode